# Problemas con html2canvas - Imagen pixeleada

Tags: css, frontend, html2canvas

Un saludo a toda la comunidad de stack overflow, tengo una duda a ver si es posible, sobre como descargar automáticamente la imagen (obtenida de la librería html2canvas con javascript)
estoy presetando el siguiente problema:

El problema está cuando descargo la imagen se ve pixeleada y borrosa.

Al principio pense que era la imagen pero la imagen está al mismo tamaño que la estoy descargando por eso me parece raro.

Estaré muy agradecido por el apoyo, solo espero que me apuedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

```js
    function save(canvas) {/*html2canvas-0.5.0 work with Promise.js*/
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "ss.png";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        a.click();
    }
    function capturePng() {
    console.log("hola capture png")
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("divPreview"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var  _canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    _canvas.setAttribute('width', 1920);
    _canvas.setAttribute('height', 1080);
    var ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.scale(5, 5);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    var dataURL = _canvas.toDataURL();  
    //document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").appendChild(_canvas);
    var image = _canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "ss.png";
    a.href = image;
    a.click();
    },
    useCORS: true
    });

    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 
 <div id="divBorder" class="divBorder">
        <div id="divPreview" class="container-center preview overText">

          <div id="textDiploma" class="tag">Aquí se mostrará tu mensaje &#128147 &#128079 &#128556</div>

          <img id="imageDemo" src="https://i.imgur.com/4RSk1bq.png" class="image-preview" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        </div>
      </div>

 <button class="button" id="btnCaptura" onclick="capturePng()">Descargar Diploma
            </button>
```

```css
.preview {
      object-fit: contain;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      
    }


    .image-preview {
      width: 100%;
      height: 80%;
      object-fit: contain;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .container-center {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .overText {
      position: relative;
    }


    .tag {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 24%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .divBorder {
      border: 10px solid #1796A7;
      margin: 0px 70px;
    }
```

Comment: Este es un bug ya conocido con la librería. En el siguiente enlace de SO hay varias entradas que podrías revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803825/html2canvas-generates-blurry-images

Answer (score 0):

```js
function save(canvas) {/*html2canvas-0.5.0 work with Promise.js*/
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "ss.png";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        a.click();
    }
    function capturePng() {
        const preview = document.getElementById("divPreview");
        preview.classList.toggle("dimensiones");
    html2canvas(preview, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var  _canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    _canvas.setAttribute('width', 1920);
    _canvas.setAttribute('height', 1080);
    var ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.scale(5, 5);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    var dataURL = _canvas.toDataURL();  
    //document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").appendChild(_canvas);
    var image = _canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "ss.png";
    a.href = image;
    a.click();
     preview.classList.toggle("dimensiones");
    },
    useCORS: true
    });
   
    }
```

```css
     .preview {
      object-fit: contain;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      
    }


    .image-preview {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .container-center {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .overText {
      position: relative;
    }


    .tag {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 24%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .divBorder {
      border: 10px solid #1796A7;
      margin: 0px 70px;
    }

    .dimensiones{
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <div id="divBorder" class="divBorder">
        <div id="divPreview" class="container-center preview overText">

          <div id="textDiploma" class="tag">Aquí se mostrará tu mensaje &#128147 &#128079 &#128556</div>

          <img id="imageDemo" src="https://i.imgur.com/4RSk1bq.png" class="image-preview" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        </div>
      </div>

 <button class="button" id="btnCaptura" onclick="capturePng()">Descargar Diploma
            </button>
```

Comment: perdona no habia puesto el css completo en la pregunta, asi se veía podrias decirme si el error es en el css

Comment: Edite la respuesta para poner la imagen que me genera a mí con los cambios que yo hice, está bien esa imagen?

Comment: si ya acabo de editar,  y si esa es la imagen 1920x1080 pero aún así colocandole al div .preview el width: fit-content;   se ve igual pixeleada

Comment: lo que creo que está pasando que está considerando el tamaño actual dentro del div y cuando se descarga se estira no respetando el tamaño original

Comment: Si ahora que está el css completo, veo que lo de fit-content no es necesario

Comment: Prueba con lo último que coloqué